# IP V6 to IP V4 conversion on an online transaction

Tags: networking, proxy, payment-gateway, ipv6, ipv4

we are using an API from a company for doing payments on our system. this company can accept only IP v4 from the user. it means if the user with IP v6 goes to the last payment step, and starts to pay with his/her credit card, the company does not accept it and payment will be failed.
my question is: is there any way to convert or change the user IPv6 to IPv4 in the last step? for example something like a proxy or something else.

I know that IP v6 and IP v4 have different mutually incompatible network addressing schemes. but is there any way to handle this process that converts or changes it by proxy or something?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "convert" an IPv6 to an IPv4 address.

There's 2^128 IPv6 addresses in the world (that's a number with 38 digits) but only 2^32 (4 billion) IPv4 addresses. There's ways to write an IPv4 address as an IPv6 address (1.2.3.4 == ::ffff:1.2.3.4 or ::ffff:102:304), but that's still an IPv4 address.

Also, there is no requirement that a client even has to have both IP versions. There could be a client that only has IPv4 (no IPv6), and there could be a client that only has IPv6 (no IPv4).

If the payment company is stuck in the past and only supports IPv4 for the payment transactions, I would recommend finding a new payment company. Do they have any support articles regarding IPv6 support? Did you contact their support and asked for suggestions?

Or is it that the company supports IPv6 just fine and *your* application doesn't? Then I'd suggest making your website support IPv6.